# Eliminate Duplicate IDs in SQL Server View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, duplicates

i am creating this view from different tables . but the problem in view some of the IDS are repeated . i want to eliminate repeated ID from it .how can i do that .I know i have to use Distinct keyword but how can i use it here ?

```
 SELECT        dbo.Dispatch.Date, dbo.Dispatch.ID AS Dispatch_ID, dbo.Dispatch.Demand_ID AS Dispatch_DemandID, dbo.Dispatch.Full_Weight, dbo.Dispatch.Empty_Weight, dbo.Dispatch.Status, dbo.Dispatch.PDate, 
                         dbo.Customer.Name AS CustomerName, dbo.Demand.ID AS Demand_ID, dbo.Material.Bulk_Bags, dbo.Material.Type AS MaterialType, dbo.Material.Name AS MaterialName, 
                         dbo.[Order].Order_ID AS Order_Order_ID, dbo.[Order].Order_Date, dbo.Dispatch.PYear, dbo.Dispatch.PWeek, dbo.Dispatch.PMonth, dbo.[Order].Total_Quantity, dbo.[Order].RatePerTon, dbo.[Order].Discount, 
                         dbo.[Order].Final_Cost, dbo.[Order].Payment_Mode, dbo.[Order].Tax, dbo.[Order].Added_Value, dbo.Dispatch.Full_Weight - dbo.Dispatch.Empty_Weight AS DeliveredQuantity, dbo.Demand.Order_ID, 
                         dbo.Total_Amount_Status.Total_Amount, dbo.Total_Amount_Status.Amount_status
FROM                     dbo.Dispatch INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Demand ON dbo.Dispatch.Demand_ID = dbo.Demand.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[Order] ON dbo.Demand.Order_ID = dbo.[Order].Order_ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Material ON dbo.[Order].Material_ID = dbo.Material.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Customer ON dbo.[Order].Customer_ID = dbo.Customer.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Total_Amount_Status ON dbo.[Order].Order_ID = dbo.Total_Amount_Status.Order_ID
WHERE        (dbo.Dispatch.Status = 'EXIT') AND (dbo.Dispatch.Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-06 00:00:00', 102)) order by Dispatch.ID desc
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.

Comment: there are many tables how i can add all tables here?

Comment: Simplify the problem, and everything will become easier for you and for us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`.

You also can have rows with same `ID`s but different data in another columns. If you dont care about what data to show you can use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
...
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dispatch_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

One note: please, use [aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: i tried distinct before .but its not working its returning duplicate dispatch_IDs
.you are right there is different data in another column but i dont want that i just want one row .how can i do that

Comment: Change `SELECT` to `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` and add `ORDER BY...` like in my answer.

Comment: You Know You are Legend . Thank You very Much .

Comment: i have one more question .can you please reply ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY XX ORDER BY XX)` [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and then select the rows which returns 1.

This should be done by using your Primary keys to identify a unique row.

Example could be like:

**SQL Code**

```
    with cte as ( SELECT        dbo.Dispatch.Date, dbo.Dispatch.ID AS Dispatch_ID, dbo.Dispatch.Demand_ID AS Dispatch_DemandID, dbo.Dispatch.Full_Weight, dbo.Dispatch.Empty_Weight, dbo.Dispatch.Status, dbo.Dispatch.PDate, 
                         dbo.Customer.Name AS CustomerName, dbo.Demand.ID AS Demand_ID, dbo.Material.Bulk_Bags, dbo.Material.Type AS MaterialType, dbo.Material.Name AS MaterialName, 
                         dbo.[Order].Order_ID AS Order_Order_ID, dbo.[Order].Order_Date, dbo.Dispatch.PYear, dbo.Dispatch.PWeek, dbo.Dispatch.PMonth, dbo.[Order].Total_Quantity, dbo.[Order].RatePerTon, dbo.[Order].Discount, 
                         dbo.[Order].Final_Cost, dbo.[Order].Payment_Mode, dbo.[Order].Tax, dbo.[Order].Added_Value, dbo.Dispatch.Full_Weight - dbo.Dispatch.Empty_Weight AS DeliveredQuantity, dbo.Demand.Order_ID, 
                         dbo.Total_Amount_Status.Total_Amount, dbo.Total_Amount_Status.Amount_status
                         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.Dispatch.ID order by dbo.Dispatch.ID) as rn
FROM                     dbo.Dispatch INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Demand ON dbo.Dispatch.Demand_ID = dbo.Demand.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[Order] ON dbo.Demand.Order_ID = dbo.[Order].Order_ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Material ON dbo.[Order].Material_ID = dbo.Material.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Customer ON dbo.[Order].Customer_ID = dbo.Customer.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Total_Amount_Status ON dbo.[Order].Order_ID = dbo.Total_Amount_Status.Order_ID
WHERE        (dbo.Dispatch.Status = 'EXIT') AND (dbo.Dispatch.Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-06 00:00:00', 102)) 

)

select * from CTE
where rn = 1
order by Dispatch_ID desc
```

Comment: it returns nothing now :(

Comment: @ROMA It should. Look at rn column in inner select in CTE and see if any rn is 1?

Comment: Brother thanks for taking the time to reply . But gofr1 answer worked for me . 
i really appreciate you Help. Stay blessed